# Finding imagesets which are labelled for object detection?

Tags: image, tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset, object-detection

I am building some object detectors with Tensorflow. Really enjoying it.

The most time-intensive part of any project I work on is gathering images and drawing bounding boxes around the relevant classes I want to detect.

In order to get good results, I need to tag at least 100 images for each class - usually more. When the class has a lot of variation - eg a "person" classifier - you need a hell of a lot more.

This brings me to my question, a lot of the famous base networks - MobileNet, VGG-Net, LeNet and the likes come pretrained on a few hundred different classes. So presumably they have pre-labeled/tagged images stored *somewhere*.

Are these available anywhere for the average developer?

I've found some - e.g from [here](https://skymind.ai/wiki/open-datasets) but they don't seem to contain the labels which would allow me to generate TFRecords to train an object detector.

**Tl;dr** - Let's say I just want to create a "person" classifier - where can I find labelled training data for this, allowing me to quickly create classes for generating TFRecords/creating an object detector in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you could make full usage of the pretrained network by transfer learning or fine-tuning  on them with your own dataset, it will save a lot of computation time, power.

But if you insist on training from scratch, there are some well-known image datasets like [OpenImages](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/index.html), [COCO](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/index.html), [Kitti](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/), etc.

These datasets contain a lot more classes other than 'person' but you can filter them out when creating tfrecord, so your tfrecord only contains bounding box information about 'person'.

Comment: the etc part of the above list is pretty large. Find some [more links to datasets](http://www.svcl.ucsd.edu/projects/universal-detection/) on the webpage of a recent paper